# sync option missing from azure under api app -> ssl settings -> .pfx certificates

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-secrets

I have run into an issue where I don't see the sync option when I go to azure app -> tls/ssl settings -> .pfx certificate. I am updating a new version of my certificate in keyvault but in my app its not allowing me to sync. Until 4 days ago I could see that sync option don't know what went wrong meanwhile

Comment: Please be careful to hide your subscription and other important information. @Simranjeet Singh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sync` option is enabled if the certificate is out of sync. Also, note that App Service automatically syncs your certificate within 48 hours. However, if you want to **force sync**, go to [App Service Certificates](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/Resources/resourceType/Microsoft.CertificateRegistration%2FcertificateOrders) page. Navigate to your certificate -> Go to **Rekey and Sync** from the left navigation -> Sync. For details, refer [TLS/SSL certificate in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate).
[image]

By the way you can also check if cert is in sync by clicking the linked cert in the bottom pane.

[image]

Comment: my azure service Certificates is blank. Does all the certificates come under that or only those which were created using azure service certificates?